# How to get drop down (combo box) value which is populated by firebase realtime database in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-realtime-database, handlebars.js

I checked several answers on stack overflow, but none seem to answer my question.
I populated drop downs (HTML Select and Option) using firebase like so:

#### Nodejs

```
function getClients() {
    const ref = firebaseApp.database().ref('clients');
    return ref.once('value').then(snap => snap.val());
}

app.get('/clients', (request,response) => {
    // response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
    getClients().then(clients => {
        response.render('clients', { clients })
    });
})
```

#### HTML (with handlebars)

```
        <label for="client">Client</label>
        <select id="client" name="client">
            <option>Choose Client</option>
            {{#each clients}}
            <option value="{{this}}">{{name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
```

The drop down is populated correctly, but my problem is what to write in the `option` value, in order to be able to get the child `key`.

#### Edit (added json equivalent of my db structure)

```
{
  "clients" : {
    "-M0wyt-_2cC2nACDArUR" : {
      "email" : "c",
      "name" : "a",
      "number" : "b"
    },
    "-M0wzLp-7p1qboJZ1srB" : {
      "email" : "e",
      "name" : "q",
      "number" : "w"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What is the shape of the client object?

Comment: Added to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change the rendering:

```
getClients().then(clients => {
   const clientArray = Object.keys(clients)
     .map(client => ({key: client, ...clients[client]}))
   console.log(clientArray)
   response.render('clients', { clients: ClientArray })
});
```

See this snippet for the data transform this map function does.

```js
const data = {
  "clients" : {
    "-M0wyt-_2cC2nACDArUR" : {
      "email" : "c",
      "name" : "a",
      "number" : "b"
    },
    "-M0wzLp-7p1qboJZ1srB" : {
      "email" : "e",
      "name" : "q",
      "number" : "w"
    }
  }
}

const clients = data.clients
const clientArray = Object.keys(clients)
   .map(client => ({key: client, ...clients[client]}))
console.log(clientArray)
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't get a notification that my question was answered. Thanks a lot.